# Having trouble getting my min and max values to display

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a GUI in windows application forms. I need this program to accept 10 numbers from the textbox and then it should take it with the click of the button and disaplay the minimum and maximum number in the last text box. I am new to coding and I cant figure out how to get this to work any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace sortnumbers
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int[] numbers = new int[10];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] items = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' },     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (items.Length != 10)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There needs to be 10 integers in the textbox, separated by spaces");
            textBox1.Focus();
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(items[i]);

        int Maxvalue = numbers.Max();//gives the max value.

         int Minvalue = numbers.Min();//gives the min value.

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You instantiate Maxvalue and Minvalue but never use them.    Try to instantiate them outside of the for loop, but continue to set them inside the loop.  Add a breakpoint to just after your for loop and inspect the values.  Do they make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your variable outside of the loop, to get the min. and max. value after populating the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     numbers[i] = int.Parse(items[i]);
}


int Maxvalue = numbers.Max();

int Minvalue = numbers.Min();
```

Then if you wanna display them for example in a label just set the Labels `Text` property:

```
// lblMin and lblMax are names of your labels
lblMin.Text = Minvalue.ToString();
lblMax.Text = Maxvalue.ToString();
```

Comment: add two labels to your form and change their name from properties window.

Answer (score 0):

I can't C# , but what I guess is this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(items[i]);

        int Maxvalue = numbers.Max();//gives the max value.

         int Minvalue = numbers.Min();//gives the min value.

        }
```

to this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(items[i])

        }
 int Maxvalue = numbers.Max();//gives the max value.

         int Minvalue = numbers.Min();//gives the min value.
```

Hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to learn about [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) as it is your bread-n-butter when manipulating collections of objects.

- Do not check for 10 items; it is unnecessary.
- No need for a for loop.

This is all that is necessary to make this work.
Declare variables using var most of the time.
Because of implicit typing and the textbox contains numbers only; this works.
The [Min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.min(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.max(v=vs.100).aspx) methods are linq extension methods.

```
var numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var min = numbers.Min();
var max = numbers.Max();
```

**UPDATE**

Add a second textbox to your form and add this line below everything.

```
textbox2.Text = string.Format("min: {0} max: {1}", min, max);
```

Comment: @ phillip  How would I get it to display like that.

Comment: you want the results put into textbox1 or a label or what?

Comment: a text box or label so I know for future reference.

Comment: it's your app...  i have no idea what you have done.  you can show it using showmessage or stuff it into a textbox or a label or a dozen other way...  that's your choice.  But if you add a second textbox called textbox2 then see my update above.

Comment: I got it to work but if user enters ( 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10) it displays 9 as my max. Why? and how do i fix it?

Comment: The type for numbers was a string[] and you need them to be int[]... I have edited the posting so that the string arrary gets converted into an int array as follows: .Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();